# jquery break apart return string from ajax

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax call to php which returns a list of `li` items as a string. 
I cannot alter the `php`part.

**ques:**  
How can i break apart the return data from an ajax call into each `li` item and push it into an array?

```
var arr = [];
$.post('process.php', function(data) {

    // data returns a string like:  "<li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li>"

    var eachLI = data.split();
    arr.push(eachLI);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery can parse your returned string as html -

```
$.post('process.php', function(data) {
    // data returns a string like:  "<li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li>"
    var eachLI = $(data);
}
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/yKkzS/4/

Comment: thank you,  when i `console.log(eachLI.length);` it returns 0.  how can i get the total count?

Comment: im trying to push those elements into an array but still un successful.  any way you can lend a hand 1 more time please

Comment: @tq  See this `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/yKkzS/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/yKkzS/3/